# About grouping results in SQL query

Tags: php, sql

Sorry if this is a really dumb question. I have a table with 3 columns: id, user_id and article_id that represents a many to many relationship between user and article tables. I'm using PHP and MySQL

Example records:

- id: 1 user_id: 5 article_id: 6 (it means that user 5 likes article 6)
- id: 2 user_id: 1 article_id: 6
- id: 3 user_id: 2 article_id: 1
- id: 4 user_id: 3 article_id: 3

i would like to group results by **article** and get an array like this one:

```
array[6] = {5,1};
array[1] = {2};
array[3] = {3};
```

so i can get the users who like every article in a convenient way. The question is, which is the best way to accomplish it? Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I'm using PHP, Doctrine and MYSQL. Symfony to be more accurate. I know i can do it by iterating over the results in php but i don't know if there's a simpler way since i'm not an expert. Sorry for my english and thanks for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate on PHP side over the results and group into array, or use `GROUP_CONCAT` and then `explode`

Comment: Thanks Distdev, i didn't know about the second way, although it seems that in Doctrine i can't use group_concat. I didn't mention it before so it's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

not being familiar with "Doctrine" syntax, if you are able to provide a query string, you should be able to get the results via

```
select article_id, group_concat( user_id ) as LikedByUsers
   from YourTable
   group by article_id
```

first column would have the article ID, and second column your comma separated list of users who like it.